# Java - Printing For Loop List Values in a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Essentially, I have a for loop and it will find the occurrences of all words that end with a specific letter, the code works fine if I do a regular system output, but I want to display the words on the JFrame Centre Panel. I am using a JLabel, and I thought the label would display all the occurrences from the loop but it only prints the last value.

Am I using the correct J component (JLabel)? If so is it possible to print all the values from the loop on the label?

```
        else if(e.getSource() == lastOccurrence) {
            textFieldVar= textField.getText().toLowerCase();
            for(String x: wordList) {
                if(x.endsWith(textFieldVar) ) {
                    System.out.println(x);
                    frameLabel.setText("The words ending with " + textFieldVar+ " are " + x);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Calling `.setText(...)` on the JLabel does just that, sets its text, and gets rid of anything else that it holds. I would use a JTextArea and append the text to it in the for loop by calling its `.append(...)` method.

Comment: Either that or concatenate the String as suggested in a deleted (why?) comment.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I looked at the duplicate answer but i still have the same issue of it now only displaying the first element? Is my only method append to a text area

Comment: The logic you use is wrong, so you only get the last item. To do what you want, you have to convey the call to `JLabel#setText()` after the body of the loop.